# how to get into sudo mode in Linux?

Tags: sudo

I am looking to achieve something like this:

> Sudo
>
> *Terminal ask for password => enter password*
>
> now I am in sudo mode

Comment: Hi, and welcome to superuser.com! Unfortunately, your question is unclear and will be closed shortly. Please edit to clarify. In particular, AFAIK there is no such thing as "sudo mode". Please explain what you mean by "sudo mode", and what it should do. Then we can probably help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's kind of difficult to determine what you want.

Sudo is generally used to either execute a single command with elevated privileges:

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

...as normally a non-root user could modify this file.  You can also use it to switch to root user:

```
sudo -i
```

or

```
sudo su -
```

However, if you need this basic of a tutorial on sudo, ***please be very careful using it.***